# Kendo UI autocomplete databound event does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, kendo-ui

I am developing a mobile application using Kendo UI. In my script file,

```
$("#name").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataBound: onChange
    });
```

Suppose my autocomplete  box has the string "abc". When I delete a letter it triggers the databound event. But I delete the last letter of autocomplete (emptying autocomplete) it does not trigger databound event. Can anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type, the auto-complete widget will filter the data source if there is any text in it; this triggers the data source change event which in turn leads to the `dataBound` event being triggered in the `AutoComplete.refresh` method (where the widget updates its view if necessary).

If there is no text in the input, then the data source is not filtered and as a result, the `dataBound` event isn't triggered (in that case, the auto-complete simply closes its popup).

If this bothers you and you want `dataBound` to be triggered when you clear the input, you can customize the widget's search method:

```
kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.search = (function (search) {
    return function (word) {
        word = word || this._accessor();
        var length = word.length;
        if (!length) {
            this.dataSource.filter({}); // clear the data source filter
        }

        search.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.search);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/e5xQZ/))